# Divergence theorem integral

Tags: calculus, integration, divergence-operator

[image]

I'm stuck on this question. For part (a), I chose g(x,y,z) = (9-x^2-y^2)/(9+x^2+y^2) - z. Then I calculated the unit normal vector which ended up being a mess. How do I use the divergence theorem for part (a)?

Comment: In part a) you're integrating over $D$ which is a portion of the $xy-$plane.  The outward-pointing normal is $\mathbf{-k},$ isn't it?

Comment: @saulspatz I'm not sure, I don't full understand the concept

Answer (score 1):

Over the Surface $D, z = 0 \implies 9 - x^2 - y^2 = 0$

or $D$ is a disk of radius $3$

$n = (0,0,-1)\\ 
F\cdot n = -y^2$

$\iint -y^2\ dD$

b) $\nabla \cdot F = x+2$

$\iiint x\ dV + 2V$ and $\iiint x\ dV=0$ as it is an odd function integrated around a symmetric region.

c) by the divergence theorem $\iint F\ dD + \iint F\ dS = \iiint \nabla \cdot F \ dV$

Comment: Ok thank you, but I how do I know what to integrate with respect to what parameters?

Comment: You should know the parameters of a disk!  $\int_{-3}^{3}\int_{-\sqrt {9-x^2}}^{\sqrt {9-x^2}} -y^2\ dy\ dx$  or convert to polar coordinates $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^3 -r^3\sin^2 \theta\ dr\ d\theta$